# j2me - Content-Disposition attachment; filename - how to get it?

Tags: http, java-me, content-disposition

I am trying to download an audio file served by Rails server with my j2me application. 
Here is my piece of code:

```
try {
    connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://host.com/user/getaudio/65/");
    connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1");

    System.out.println("HTTP Response: " + connection.getResponseMessage()); // OK
    System.out.println("HTTP ResponseCode: " + connection.getResponseCode()); // 200
    System.out.println("HTTP ResponseLength: " + connection.getLength()); // -1

    connection.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The HTTP response is OK, code: 200. Everything is fine but the connection.getLength() returns -1. I have realized that the file is attached via Content-Disposition header. 
I know how to reach it with connection.getHeaderField() but what next? 
Is it possible to reach it somehow?

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

-1 probably means that the content length isn't known upfront. Just read from the connection until there's no more data.